# How to access `$scope.search.value`?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am developing an app in ionic framework.

I found a directive of search bar for ionic on Google, and it works.

```js
    .directive('ionSearch', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                getData: '&source',
                model: '=?',
                search: '=?filter'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.minLength = attrs.minLength || 0;
                scope.placeholder = attrs.placeholder || '';
                scope.search = {value: ''};

                if (attrs.class)
                    element.addClass(attrs.class);

                if (attrs.source) {
                    scope.$watch('search.value', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                        if (newValue.length > attrs.minLength) {
                            scope.getData({str: newValue}).then(function (results) {
                                scope.model = results;
                            });
                        } else {
                            scope.model = [];
                        }
                    });
                }

                scope.clearSearch = function() {
                    scope.search.value = '';
                };
            },
            template: '<div class="item-input-wrapper">' +
            '<i class="icon ion-android-search"></i>' +
            '<input type="search" placeholder="{{placeholder}}"  ng-model="search.value">' +
            '<i ng-if="search.value.length > 0" ng-click="clearSearch()" class="icon ion-close"></i>' +
            '</div>'
        };
    })
```

```html
<ion-content overflow-scroll='true'>
      <div class="bar bar-header  item-input-inset">
        <ion-search class="search-wrapper-light" placeholder="Search..." min-length="1" model="results" source="getExamsByName(str)"></ion-search>
      </div>
    <div ng-if="exams">
      <p>Found {{exams.length}} results </p>
      <p>{{search.value|json}}</p>
    </div>
    <ion-list>
      .....
      ...
    </ion-list>
```

---

But I don't know how to access the `$scope.search.value`, (i.e. the input text).

I had tried in my html file `{{search.value}}`, but it shows nothing.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you wanted to access value created from directive..outside directive elememt?

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes, I want to show it  under the search bar. Just like the angularjs tutorial that shows two way binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your directive has an isolated scope, i.e. you can not directly access the scope variables of the directive from outside.

Fortunately, the `search` variable is already bound to the outside scope by `search: '=?filter'`. This means, if your directive has the filter attribute, this variable is two-way bound.

Hence, if you enhance your HTML like the following

```
 <ion-search class="search-wrapper-light" placeholder="Search..." min-length="1" model="results" source="getExamsByName(str)" filter="search"></ion-search>
```

then the outside scope variable `search` will hold the search scope variable from inside the directive.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using `=?filter` in your directive, `=` does meant that you are using two way data binding in your directive, but `?` that it could be optional variable & the 3rd part is `filter` that is for attribute name. You should have include the `filter` attribute with some value in your directive element, Also you controller should have value defined like `$scope.search = {}` so that initially it would be an object.

**Markup**

```
<ion-search class="search-wrapper-light" placeholder="Search..." min-length="1" 
  model="results" source="getExamsByName(str)" filter="search">
</ion-search>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `search` property on your isolated scope. Shouldn’t that be `source`?